# The result for ANOVA using scipy and sklearn are different

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, anova

I have a dataframe df and I have two columns. One is 'score' and other one is 'target'. It is a binary classification problem with 'target' taking up 0/1 values. The other column 'score' is a numerical feature with minimum value 0 and maximum value 1000. There are no NaN values in the dataframe.

The results using scipy are shown below:

```
fvalue, pvalue = stats.f_oneway(df['score'], df['target'])
print(fvalue, pvalue) 
982028.2400045951 0.0
```

The results using sklearn are shown below:

```
f_test, f_test_p = f_classif(df[['score']].values, df[['target']].values)
print(f_test, f_test_p) 
[193950.8247209] [0.]
```

Can some suggest some methods, why they are giving different results?

**Thanks for the help in advance**

Comment: This is probably a better question for the Statistics Stackexchange than for here. I'm guessing it's due to a numerical or rounding error, but the people on the stats site would probably be able to explain which library uses which solution method and why that matters.